# sql - Installing unequal data into a table where another attribute is the same

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want insert username for some company, but username should not be repeat in one company.

```
id | company_name|                  id|username|company |
---|-------------|                  --|--------|--------|
1  |   company1  |                  1 | admin  |company1| !!
2  |   company2  | 1 ------------ M 2 | admin  |company1| !!
3  |   company3  |                  3 | admin  |company2|
```

Comment: 1. Create a unique index on the username column 2. check to see if a username exists *before* you try to insert a record conatining it

Comment: I'v up voted @JohnConde comment, and have another question, why do you need second table in this situation then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a unique index in the second table:  `table2(username, company)`.

If you attempt to insert a duplicate user name within a company, then you will get an error.